# Is it acceptable to ask to Upvote/Accept for the answer if it clarifies the issue?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer

After posting an answer to address the issue on Stack Exchange sites, would it be appropriate to kindly request community member to consider accepting or up-voting the answer if it resolves their issue, perhaps as a comment, after one or two days if they are unresponsive?

Comment: Yes, it helped. We can ask if they are unresponsive.

Comment: While the top answer to that linked post says it's okay, note that the [privilege page for comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) does *not* list this as a valid reason for commenting. So it's likely each site will have their own policy on this.

Comment: There would be nothing to *stop* you. However, I do flag such comments for removal on sight. And AFAIK, they've always been removed on any stack I've flagged them.

Comment: If the owner of the question is not responding we can use; if the owner is responding we don't use it right.

Comment: Asking for acceptance in answers is pollution, imagine a post with ten answers where each one has a comment *"Hey, I was nice to you and now you must be nice to me, accept my answer for the good of my cause"*, it makes me sick just thinking about. If the questioner doesn't come to accept an answer, I think it's fair to add a comment to the question advising what acceptance is and how to go about it—a link to a local META publication explaining why and how the acceptance process works can also be provided.

Comment: Why would it become polluted? People from different countries doesn't share the same mindset. Some need remainders. We put a lot of effort into crafting that solution, so what's the issue with it?

Comment: And I am not saying this to ask when the owner is responding. This comes to picture when he is not active after we have put a lot of effort to provide the solution.

Comment: I think you've got it wrong. This isn't a debate, I've guided you to use the platform; now it's up to you whether or not to accept the guidance. If you don't accept the guidance and start practicing behavior that is frowned upon, don't expect sympathy from other users.